# Remove listener from com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-architecture-components

I am using `FirebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword` to register a user in Firebase. The method returns `Task<AuthResult>` that I can use to add a listener:

`Task.addOnCompleteListener(my_listener)`

I was wondering if there is a way to remove the `my_listener` from the Task when I don't want to listen for a result anymore.

I am using FirebaseAuth methods inside ViewModel and I would like to remove these listeners in `ViewModel.onCleared()`.

Comment: Sadly, the `addOnCompleteListener` method is attached to the Activity's lifecycle. As you can see in [the docs](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/tasks/Task.html#addOnCompleteListener(com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener%3CTResult%3E)), the listener will only be removed in `Activity.onStop()`. I suggest taking the FirebaseAuth methods out of the viewModel scope.